# input string only

Tags: string, python-2.7

How do I ask the user to input the string only. If there isn't such a thing how do I set it so that if they enter anything else it would ask the user to re-enter.

This is what I have tried (it doesn't work):

```
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
 if name != str(name):
     name = raw_input("Error, please re-enter : ")
```

Comment: By string do you mean only contains letters, if so is there any requirement for foreign characters?

Comment: What do you mean *"input the string only"*? The user's `raw_input` is **always a string**.

Comment: yeah but i only want the user to enter text and nothing else such as numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    userInput = raw_input("Enter a string only")
    if type(userInput) not str:
        continue
    else:
        print "You entered a STR data type. Congratulations"
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to check user input before you proceed.

In your code you'd say:

```
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    if type(name) != int         #if input isn't int then it's likely to be text so proceed
      if name != str(name):
         name = raw_input("Error, please re-enter : ")
```

You can make the above in a loop so you don't have to rewrite your code

This worked with me:

```
x = input("enter letters only")
if type(x) == int:
    print "you entered number"
else:
    print "you entered letters"
```

This works only if user inputs text in quotes like "tom" not tom